# Debugging Intermittent 500 Internal Server error & 404 Not Found

Tags: javascript, php, apache, http-status-code-404

I'm having an issue with an intermittent 500 internal server error. The error will sometimes appear every 2nd or 3rd page refresh, and sometimes it will not appear for a few hours and then suddenly popup. I've also noticed I am getting intermittent 404 not found errors on some files. The apache error_log returns no errors, and I wonder if it is a coding issue. If it is a coding issue why would it be intermittent and why would I get random 404 errors to files that DO exist?

What steps does SO recommend to go about determining and debugging a situation like this? Does anyone have any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Also, I am not hitting any process limit(s) and these errors are exclusive to JS (.php) files.

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at your apache error-log

Comment: Sorry, miss-type: I meant my apache error_log returns no errors.

Comment: is there a proxy server between the incoming web requests and the apache server? check all error logs

Comment: I don't think so - I have it on a VPS through HostGator. I have a ticket in with the admins to take a look at it (the phone support tech tried to recreate the issue and was unable to). I get the issue quite often, although I was logged in. Could it be related to a Session?

Comment: what does the php error log say(assuming you havent done something like disable error reporting or error logging, either via global or script level config).

Comment: I do notice some errors in the error_log for PHP, I'm going to work through and see if I can debug them. I am running JAXL which spits out a log to the error_log. I noticed it was 6.8MB before and I cleared it out. I also just restarted my computer and can not recreate any errors now. I wonder if the size of the error_log was causing the issue?

Comment: What instrumentation does HostGator give you? My gut is saying you are running out of RAM. There's nothing here to support that supposition, but if you can watch your memory usage on the server you might be able to confirm or rule it out.

Comment: I have 2304MB of RAM on a server with only really 1 site on it still under dev. (1-2 Users max on the website) I can't really see it being a RAM issue? Since I restarted my computer I haven't seen any of the errors so I am truly baffled ATM. I worked through the errors in the error_log so I guess we'll see what happens! I'll post again if i see the error. Thanks a ton for all your help SO!